# Decomposition of fiber product of $G$-sets in $G$-orbits

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K, H \leq G$ two subgroups. Then
the right quotients $G/H $ and $G/K$ become
naturally left $G$-sets via $\rho: G \times G/H \to G/H,
(g, fH) \mapsto gfH$  (we will work only with left $G$-sets
and omit the word left.)
The product $G/H \times G/K$ (or more ginerally any finite product $\prod_i G/H_i$)
can be naturally endowed
with structure of a $G$-set  by diagonal $G$-action
$(g,(aH, bK)) \mapsto (gaH, gbK)$.

In Tammo tom Dieck's book 'Transformation Groups' is
stated (Prop 1., page 19) that there are bijections
between following sets

(i) $G$-orbits of $G/H \times G/K$
(ii) $H$-orbits of $G/K$ with left $H$-action
(iii) Double cosets $HgK, g \in G$

In the proof the $G$-orbit $G \cdot (eH, gK)$ of $G/H \times G/K$
corresponds to the $H$-orbit $H \cdot gK$ of $G/K$ and to the
double coset $HgK$.
This implies that we can decompose $G/H \times G/K$ as set in
$G$-orbits as follows

$$ G/H \times G/K = 
  \dot\bigcup_{HgK \in H \setminus G / K}   G \cdot (eH, gK)$$

where $e \in G$ is the identity element and the disjoint
union runs over all representators $\overline{g}$ of
double cosets $HgK \in H \setminus G / K$.

But we can say even more. Since $G$ acts on any orbit
$G \cdot (eH, gK)$ transitively and the stabilizer
of $(eH,gK)$ is $H \cap gKg^{-1} = H \cap K^{g^{-1}}$, the
orbit $G \cdot (eH, gK)$ is isomorphic to $G/(H \cap K^{g^{-1}})$
and therefore the
decomposition in $G$-orbits of $G/H \times G/K$ is isomorphic to

$$  \dot\bigcup_{HgK \in H \setminus G / K}   G \cdot (eH, gK) 
G/(H \cap K^{g^{-1}})$$

**Question:** Is there a natural similar decomposition of the fiber
product $F:= G/H \times_{G/B} G/K$ possible, which sits in
diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G/H \times_{G/B} G/K @>{}  >> G/K \\
@VVV  @VVR_y: \ (gK \mapsto gyB)V  \\
G/H @>{R_x: \ (gH \mapsto gxB)}>> G/B
\end{CD}
$$

where the $x, y \in G$ satisfying $x^{-1}Hx \subset B, 
y^{-1}Ky \subset B$ define the $G$-maps
$R_x: G/H \to G/B, gH \to gxB$ and
$R_y: G/K \to G/B, gK \to gyB$.

(Note that up to isomorphism every $G$-map
$f: G/A \to G/B$ is given by a
$R_x: G/A \to G/B, gA \mapsto gxB$ where $x$ must satisfy
$x^{-1}Ax \subset B$. (note that $x$ and $x' \in G$ define same
$R_x$ iff $x'x^{-1} \in B$.)

What we know: set theoretically we have
$F= G/H \times_{G/B} G/K \subset G/H \times G/K$ and
$F$ consists of pairs $(aH, bK)$ with
$axB= byB$. Since $R_x$ and $R_y$ are $G$-maps,
if a $(aH,bK) \in F$, then the complete $G$-orbit
$G \cdot (aH,bK)$ is contained in $F$. Therefore we can
assume $(aH,bK)=(eH, gK) \in F$. Then $xB= gyB$ implies
$x^{-1}gy \in B$. That appears to be our neccessary and
sufficent condition.

So the claim is that $F = G/H \times_{G/B} G/K$ decomposes
in $G$-orbits as

$$F = G/H \times_{G/B} G/K = 
\dot\bigcup_{HgK \in H \setminus G / K, \ x^{-1}gy \in B}   
G/(H \cap K^{g^{-1}})$$

Problem: the parametrizing set
$HgK \in H \setminus G / K, \ x^{-1}gy \in B$
looks not really nice, especially I would like to get
rid of the $x^{-1}gy \in B$ condition. Can the fiber product $F = G/H \times_{G/B} G/K$ be
decomposed in orbits over a more amenable parametrizing set
without this $x^{-1}gy \in B$ condition?

Maybe there exist a parametrization over double coset $H^x \setminus B / K^y$? Can the later be somehow
related to the double coset $\{HgK \in H \setminus G / K
\ \vert \ x^{-1}gy \in B \}$?

Comment: whats B supposed to be

Comment: $B \leq G$ is a further subgroup of $G$. it is introduced in the commutative diagram above

Comment: So its an arbitrary group containing $K$ and $H$ or the normaliser of $K, H$? (that probably wont make a difference though)

Comment: No, it's a fixed part of the data of the pullback diagram. the morphisms $R_x: G/H \to G/B, gH \to gxB$ and 
$R_y: G/K \to G/B, gK \to gyB$ define this data and $F$ is the pullback. but note, in order that $R_x$ and $R_y$ are welldefined, the conjugates $H^x, K^y $ should be contained in $B$. in other words what we do is we consider a pullback defined by these two $G$-maps $R_x, R_y$ where $G/B$ is the codomain of these and want to decompose it in $G$-orbits.

Comment: @s.harp: note also that $H^x$ is shorthand notation for $x^{-1}Hx$.